# Harvard Style Bibliography not as expected

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

I would like to create bibliography in LaTeX using Harvard Style referencing.

I wasn't able to find an exact solution to this and therefore I thought to ask here.

I have 3 different materials to reference, bellow is how I expect them to be in LaTeX as well:

1) Wiki

```
Wiki name. Year. Title of article. [Online]. [Date accessed]. Available from: URL
```

2) Website

```
Family name, INITIAL(S) (or company name). Year. Title. [Online]. [Date accessed]. Available from: URL
```

3) Unpublished document

```
Family name, INITIAL(S). Year (if applicable). Title. Unpublished.
```

Here is some code from my .bib file:

```
@unpublished{refUnbublished,
    Author = {Company},
    Month = {December},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Year = {2015}}

@website{refWebsite,
    Author = {Website},
    Month = mar,
    Timestamp = {2016.04.29},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Url = {https://www.website.com/},
    Year = {2016},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://www.website.com/}}

@website{refWikipedia,
    Author = {Wikipedia},
    Timestamp = {2016.05.14},
    Title = {Some Wiki Article},
    Url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki},
    Year = {2016},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/}}
```

Here is some code from the main.tex

```
\usepackage{natbib} % Imports Bibliography system
.
.
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

But as mentioned, I was expecting it to be:

```
Wikipedia. 2016. Some wiki article. [Online]. 02 July 2016. Available from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/

Website. 2016. Some title. [Online]. 02 July 2016. Available from: https://www.website.com

Company. 2015. Some title. Unpublished.
```